# How to copy NSObject without keeping its reference to the old copied object?

Tags: ios, nsobject

```
@class BaseItem : NSObject

@end
```

I want to 'copy' an instance of BaseItem, to a new instance of BaseItem. I want to keep all its properties and values, however, i don't want to keep the old item's reference/pointer.

Comment: Please add more code. Are you talking about inheritance or allocated object referencing?

Comment: @rcat24, Did you got answer of this question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your `BaseItem` adopt the [NSCopying](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying) protocol (that is, implement the [copyWithZone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCopying/copyWithZone:) method) then you can do something like:

```
BaseItem *item = [[BaseItem alloc] init]
BaseItem *copiedItem = [item copy]
```

*P.S: `NSObject` [doesn't support](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/copy) `NSCopying` itself, so you need to explicitly adopt it in your class.*

Answer (score 1):

Local variables default to `strong`.
Setting the original pointer to nil will remove it. That's something ARC does during during compile time.

```
BaseItem *baseItem = ...;
BaseItem *baseItem2 = [baseItem copy];
baseItem = nil;
```

Comment: What if I can't nil the old one? that I need to keep both?

Comment: As long as you still have a strong reference to the original baseItem object it will be kept in memory. Since baseItem2 is only a shallow copy, all the reference properties held by baseItem will be reused by baseItem2, so it won't use up new memory for the properties. If you want to also make copies of the properties you need a deep copy.